# Send Data from Apple watch to iPhone in background

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I'm developing an app for Apple Watch, which captures the heart rate and sends it to the iPhone in real-time.

The problem is that when the display sleeps, the data is no longer sent, and when the display wakes (by touching the screen), it resumes sending/duplicating data values.

I tried to search if there was a way to stop the display from sleeping, but I do not think you can do that.

How can my app continue to collect and send data properly in the background?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any background app mode which would let your code run, after the watch goes to sleep (or after pressing the digital crown to switch to the watch face).

Your app wouldn't be running at that point. The watch suspends a foreground app when the watch goes to sleep. It activates the foreground app when the watch wakes again.

Although HealthKit will continue to collect data, you wouldn't be able to run any code while suspended to either query or send that data to the phone, even if you started a `HKWorkoutSession`.

*The watch may also terminate your app while it is suspended, depending on memory constraints, without any notification.*